# Why won't my React site redirect to the home page after signing up or signing in?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, postman

I'm trying to create a simple React site where a user can sign up on the home page or sign in if the user already has an account.

I want the home page to be the SignUp component if the user has not signed up or signed in, but I want a different home page if a user is logged in.

I'm using Axios to post/get the user information. It posts information correctly but nothing happens after the user adds a new user!

Here is my code:

Layout Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import AboutUs from '../AboutUs';
import Header from '../Header';
import SignUp from '../SignUp';
import Home from '../Home';

export default class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedInUser: ''
        };
    }

    setLoggedInUser = (user) => {
        this.setState({
            loggedInUser: user
        });

        this.props.history.push('/');
    };

    render() {
        // THESE JUST DETERMINE WHAT THE HOME URLs SHOULD BE, IF LOGGED IN. 
        // MUST STILL USE LOGIC TO RE-DIRECT.
        let routes = (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} exact />
                <Route path='/' component={SignUp} exact />
            </React.Fragment>
        )

        if (this.loggedInUser) {
            routes = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Route path='/home' component={Home} exact />
                    <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Header submit={this.signInSubmitHandler} loggedInUser={this.state.loggedInUser} />
                <Route path='/about' component={AboutUs} exact />
                {routes}              
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Header Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.signInSubmitHandler = this.signInSubmitHandler.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    signInSubmitHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const user = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/login", user)
            .then(
                response => { this.props.setLoggedInUser(response.data); }
            )
            .catch(
                response => { console.log("In the future, add logic to navigate to an error page.") }
        );      
        if (user !== null){
            alert("User signed in successfully!");
        } 
        //super.setLoggedInUser(user);
    }

    render() {
        let links;

        let searchBar;

        return (
            <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
                    <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Student Portal</NavLink>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about">About</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/sign-out">Sign Out</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        {/*<form className="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                            <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                            <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>*/}
                        <form onSubmit={this.signInSubmitHandler} className="search-bar form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                            <input name="email" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" aria-label="email" />
                            <input name="password" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Password" aria-label="password" />
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0">Sign In</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Sign In Component:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import '../css/SignUp.css';
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default class SignUp extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                age: '',
                telephone: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                addedUser: false
            };
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.signUpSubmitHandler = this.signUpSubmitHandler.bind(this);
        }

        handleChange = (event) => {
            const name = event.target.value;
            const value = event.target.value;
            this.setState({
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            });
        }

        signUpSubmitHandler = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const student = {
                firstName: this.state.firstName,
                lastName: this.state.lastName,
                age: this.state.age,
                telephone: this.state.telephone,
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            };

            axios.post("http://localhost:8080/submitStudentDetails", student)
                .then( 
                    response => { 
                        alert("Added " + this.state.firstName) 
                    }
                )
                .catch(
                    error => { 
                        alert("Error")
                     }
            );

        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="col-md-6 mx-auto text-center">
                            <div className="header-title">
                                <h1 className="wv-heading--title">
                                    Sign up — it’s free!
                                </h1>
                                <h2 className="wv-heading--subtitle">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet! Neque porro quisquam est qui do dolor amet, adipisci velit...
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4 mx-auto">
                                <div className="myform form ">
                                    <form onSubmit={this.signUpSubmitHandler} name="signUp">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="age" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="telephone" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Telephone" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="password" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="text-center ">
                                            <button type="submit" className=" btn btn-block send-button tx-tfm">Create Your Free Account</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-md-12 ">
                                            <div className="login-or">
                                                <hr className="hr-or" />     
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            <p className="small mt-3">By signing up, you are indicating that you have read and agree to the <a href="#" className="ps-hero__content__link">Terms of Use</a> and <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>.
                                            </p>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Home Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            students: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>HOME: logged in!</h1>
                <p>Welcome!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make a codesandbox, 

what happens when you complete the sign-in?  Normally if the sign-in method returns a valid response a callback with the redirect should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

you must change

```
  if (this.loggedInUser) 
  // to
  if (this.state.loggedInUser)
```